# How do I input more than one sequence into a CNN in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I'm brand new to TensorFlow and working through an example similar to the text classification guide [here](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/guides/text-classification/step-4)

I have a working model with a single sequence, but I'm trying to figure out how to have two distinct sequences for each observation enter into the model training. I could just concatenate the two sequences and have them enter as one, but I'd like each sequence to be distinct.

I looked at the documentation for the input shape argument and that led me to attempt to input the training data as a tuple of the shapes of each sequence (see below), but that did not seem to do it:

```
x_train = [x_trainfirst, x_trainlast]
x_val = [x_valfirst, x_vallast]
shape_param = tuple([i.shape[1] for i in x_train])

ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 2 arrays: [array([[ 0,  0,  0, ..., 21,  5,  4],
   [ 0,  0,  0, ..., 10,  1, 11],
   [ 0,  0,  0, ..., 26,  8,  7],
   ..., 
   [ 0,  0,  0, ..., 10,  2,  3],
   [ 0,  0,  0, ...,  8,  7,  ...
```

Any suggestions or pointers to examples/resources for running multiple sequences into a CNN would be much appreciated!

EDIT: Showing architecture and dimensions as suggested:

```
def sepcnn_model(blocks,
                 filters,
                 kernel_size,
                 embedding_dim,
                 dropout_rate,
                 pool_size,
                 input_shape,
                 num_classes,
                 num_features,
                 use_pretrained_embedding=False,
                 is_embedding_trainable=False,
                 embedding_matrix=None):
    """Creates an instance of a separable CNN model.

    # Arguments
        blocks: int, number of pairs of sepCNN and pooling blocks in the model.
        filters: int, output dimension of the layers.
        kernel_size: int, length of the convolution window.
        embedding_dim: int, dimension of the embedding vectors.
        dropout_rate: float, percentage of input to drop at Dropout layers.
        pool_size: int, factor by which to downscale input at MaxPooling layer.
        input_shape: tuple, shape of input to the model.
        num_classes: int, number of output classes.
        num_features: int, number of words (embedding input dimension).
        use_pretrained_embedding: bool, true if pre-trained embedding is on.
        is_embedding_trainable: bool, true if embedding layer is trainable.
        embedding_matrix: dict, dictionary with embedding coefficients.

    # Returns
        A sepCNN model instance.
    """
    op_units, op_activation = _get_last_layer_units_and_activation(num_classes)
    model = models.Sequential()

    # Add embedding layer. If pre-trained embedding is used add weights to the
    # embeddings layer and set trainable to input is_embedding_trainable flag.
    if use_pretrained_embedding:
        model.add(Embedding(input_dim=num_features,
                            output_dim=embedding_dim,
                            input_length=input_shape[0],
                            weights=[embedding_matrix],
                            trainable=is_embedding_trainable))
    else:
        model.add(Embedding(input_dim=num_features,
                            output_dim=embedding_dim,
                            input_length=input_shape[0]))

    for _ in range(blocks-1):
        model.add(Dropout(rate=dropout_rate))
        model.add(SeparableConv1D(filters=filters,
                                  kernel_size=kernel_size,
                                  activation='relu',
                                  bias_initializer='random_uniform',
                                  depthwise_initializer='random_uniform',
                                  padding='same'))
        model.add(SeparableConv1D(filters=filters,
                                  kernel_size=kernel_size,
                                  activation='relu',
                                  bias_initializer='random_uniform',
                                  depthwise_initializer='random_uniform',
                                  padding='same'))
        model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=pool_size))

    model.add(SeparableConv1D(filters=filters * 2,
                              kernel_size=kernel_size,
                              activation='relu',
                              bias_initializer='random_uniform',
                              depthwise_initializer='random_uniform',
                              padding='same'))
    model.add(SeparableConv1D(filters=filters * 2,
                              kernel_size=kernel_size,
                              activation='relu',
                              bias_initializer='random_uniform',
                              depthwise_initializer='random_uniform',
                              padding='same'))
    model.add(GlobalAveragePooling1D())
    model.add(Dropout(rate=dropout_rate))
    model.add(Dense(op_units, activation=op_activation))
    return model

learning_rate=1e-3
epochs=1000
batch_size=128
blocks=2
filters=64
dropout_rate=0.2
embedding_dim=200
kernel_size=3
pool_size=3

# trying to get multiple features
(training_data_fname, training_data_lname, training_labels), (val_data_fname, val_data_lname, val_labels) = tupleData #data

# Verify that validation labels are in the same range as training labels.
num_classes = get_num_classes(train_labels)
unexpected_labels = [v for v in val_labels if v not in range(num_classes)]

# if len(%unaliasexpected_labels):
#     raise ValueError('Unexpected label values found in the validation set:'
#                      ' {unexpected_labels}. Please make sure that the '
#                      'labels in the validation set are in the same range '
#                      'as training labels.'.format(
#                          unexpected_labels=unexpected_labels))

# Vectorize texts.
x_trainfirst, x_valfirst, word_index_first = sequence_vectorize(
        training_data_fname, val_data_fname)

x_trainlast, x_vallast, word_index_last = sequence_vectorize(
        training_data_lname, val_data_lname)
# Number of features will be the embedding input dimension. Add 1 for the
# reserved index 0.
num_features = min(len(word_index_first) + 1, len(word_index_last) + 1, TOP_K)

x_train = [x_trainfirst, x_trainlast]
x_val = [x_valfirst, x_vallast]

shape_param = tuple([i.shape[1] for i in x_train])


# Create model instance.
model = sepcnn_model(blocks=blocks,
                                 filters=filters,
                                 kernel_size=kernel_size,
                                 embedding_dim=embedding_dim,
                                 dropout_rate=dropout_rate,
                                 pool_size=pool_size,
                                 input_shape=shape_param, #x_train.shape[1:],
                                 num_classes=num_classes,
                                 num_features=num_features)

# Compile model with learning parameters.
if num_classes == 2:
    loss = 'binary_crossentropy'
else:
    loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy'
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=learning_rate)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss, metrics=['acc'])

# Create callback for early stopping on validation loss. If the loss does
# not decrease in two consecutive tries, stop training.
callbacks = [tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
    monitor='val_loss', patience=2)]

# Train and validate model.
history = model.fit(
        x_train,
        train_labels,
        epochs=epochs,
        callbacks=callbacks,
        validation_data=(x_val, val_labels),
        verbose=2,  # Logs once per epoch.
        batch_size=batch_size)

# Print results.
history = history.history
print('Validation accuracy: {acc}, loss: {loss}'.format(
        acc=history['val_acc'][-1], loss=history['val_loss'][-1]))

# Save model.
model.save('sepcnn_model.h5')
#return history['val_acc'][-1], history['val_loss'][-1], model
```

```
tupleData = (training_data_fname, training_data_lname, training_labels), (val_data_fname, val_data_lname, val_labels)

shape_param = tuple([i.shape[1] for i in x_train])
shape_param
1
shape_param = tuple([i.shape[1] for i in x_train])
shape_param
(17, 22)

print(x_trainfirst.shape)
(50000, 17)
print(x_trainlast.shape)
(50000, 22)

x_trainfirst[0]
array([ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 18,  2, 21,  5,  4], dtype=int32)

x_trainlast[0]
array([ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 10,
        2,  3,  7,  5,  4], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Please add model architecture and dimensions of inputs, that will help to answer your question correctly.

Comment: @AnkishBansal Good call. Added the functions I'm using and the dimensions of the inputs.

Comment: If i understand it correctly, you want to send two sequence, which are independent then on basis of that you want to classify it. It means you want to learn the correlation between sequences?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I'd like to capture any interactions between them and the class, while also treating them separately as the components of each sequence will have a different relationship with the class.

Comment: Sorry, for long time no response. I will add a possible idea probabaly today

Comment: No problem! Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try out something like following.

1. Create one network, whose input will be sequence and output will be of some dims, let's suppose `32`. Now this `32` dims represent the feature for the sequence.
2. Pass other sequence through the same network.
3. Now, you have `32` dims vectors for each sequence. You can `concatenate` these features and use these `64` dims vectors as input of another model(it can be simple feed forward network), whose output will be its target(whether both sequence are same or not).

This way you can capture the relation between two sequence.

Note: Before feeding the sequence into network, make sure both have `same` dims.

More you can read [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi7tsau-vHfAhWabisKHU4iCbwQFjAAegQICBAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.cmu.edu%2F~rsalakhu%2Fpapers%2Foneshot1.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0gKET0McCdIoco9UX2KcsE), where it is used to find the similarity between faces.